# google search box java script

Tags: javascript

I have created a google search box java script, I have applied it in iWeb, it appears well, but when I make a search it doesn't respond.

Here is the code:

```
 <!-- Put the following javascript before the closing </head> tag. -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script>
(function() {
var cx = '012476238773441236228:ivxtfsk4-uc';
var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async =     true;
gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>

<!-- Place this tag where you want both of the search box and the search results to render   -->
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Comment: can your show more code?
have you placed the javascript into your head and the tag into your body?

Comment: tag should be `javascript` and  not `java` `script`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your provided script works (as seen in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PzKLt/)).  You can safely remove the `<!DocType` meta tag.

e.g.

```
<head>
  <!-- Current head content here -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var cx = '012476238773441236228:ivxtfsk4-uc';
      var gcse = document.createElement('script');
      gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
      gcse.async = true;
      gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })();​
  </script>

</head>
```

And in your body, wherever you want your box to appear:

```
<gcse:search></gcse:search>​
```

Perhaps you can create a jsFiddle with your current code for debug help?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to insert this code through an HTML iWeb Snippet into an iWeb design page. It appears fine in the design page, and also appears  in the Browser, but... when I test it, it doesn't respond…Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok found the problem..It was working, but now I need to open the search results on a new page